# Run rake tasks from engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an engine located in

```
apps/my_engine
```

How can I run a rake task that is currently located in `apps/my_engine/lib/tasks`?

When I try to run it I get an "Don't know how to build task" error.

This is how my Rakefile looks like in the engine:

```
begin
  require 'bundler/setup'
rescue LoadError
  puts 'You must `gem install bundler` and `bundle install` to run rake tasks'
end

require 'rdoc/task'

RDoc::Task.new(:rdoc) do |rdoc|
  rdoc.rdoc_dir = 'rdoc'
  rdoc.title    = 'GoalSaver'
  rdoc.options << '--line-numbers'
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include('README.rdoc')
  rdoc.rdoc_files.include('lib/**/*.rb')
end

APP_RAKEFILE = File.expand_path("../test/dummy/Rakefile", __FILE__)
load 'rails/tasks/engine.rake'

Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks

require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << 'lib'
  t.libs << 'test'
  t.pattern = 'test/**/*_test.rb'
  t.verbose = false
end

task default: :test
```

Comment: i just started trying to do the same. in my case i have an engine that only has models and biz services(not web services). 

i don't want run the dummy app to test just want to run rake test.

have you made any progress?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to extend your main application with engine's rake tasks. Yush, it is possible. Just define your tasks in `apps/my_engine/lib/tasks`, leaving the engine's Rakefile alone. The former is not loaded into main app's context.

An example:

```
# apps/my_engine/lib/tasks/admin.rb
namespace :'admin-ui' do
  desc 'reload it!'
  task :reload do
    warn 'reloading!'
  end
end


# apps/my_engine/Rakefile
require "bundler/gem_tasks"
```